# DO Kubernetes Cluster + GCP Container Registry

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, digital-ocean, google-container-registry

I have a Kubernetes cluster in Digital Ocean, I want to pull the images from a private repository in GCP.

I tried to create a secret that make me able to to pull the images following this article https://blog.container-solutions.com/using-google-container-registry-with-kubernetes

Basically, these are the steps

1. In the GCP account, create a service account key, with a JSON credential
2. Execute

   ```
   kubectl create secret docker-registry gcr-json-key \
     --docker-server=gcr.io \
     --docker-username=_json_key \
     --docker-password="$(cat ~/json-key-file.json)" \
     --docker-email=any@valid.email
   ```
3. In the deployment yaml reference the secret

   ```
   imagePullSecrets:
     - name: gcr-json-key
   ```

I don't understand why I am getting 403. If there are some restriccions to use the registry outside google cloud, or if I missed some configuration something.

> Failed to pull image "gcr.io/myapp/backendnodeapi:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "gcr.io/myapp/backendnodeapi:latest": failed to resolve reference "gcr.io/myapp/backendnodeapi:latest": unexpected status code [manifests latest]: 403 Forbidden

Comment: Your approach is good and you can definitely use GCR remotely. I've used it with DO Managed Kubernetes. Double check whether `docker-server` requires the `https://` prefix and that you can `cat ~/json-key-file.json`. I assume you're creating the Secret and the Deployment in the same Namespace.

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks for your comment, I enabled the https, I also verified that the secret was created in the same namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that you have enabled the Container Registry API, Installed Cloud SDK and Service account you are using for authentication has [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) to access Container Registry.

Docker requires privileged access to interact with registries. On Linux or Windows, add the user that you use to run Docker commands to the Docker security group.
This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#prereqs) has details on prerequisites for container registry.

**Note**:
Ensure that the version of kubectl is the [latest version](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-linux).

I tried replicating by following the document you provided and it worked at my end, So ensure that all the prerequisites are met.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it seems that the account was missing some permission, it was strange because I was using this same account on google cloud. I created a new account, give `Role Viewer` permissions and now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

That JSON string is not a password.

The documentation suggests to either activate the service account:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account [USERNAME]@[PROJECT-ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=~/service-account.json
```

Or add the configuration to `$HOME/.docker/config.json`

And then run `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker`.

---

Kubernetes seems to demand a [service-account token secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#service-account-token-secrets)

and this requires annotation `kubernetes.io/service-account.name`.

Also see [Configure Service Accounts for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I verified that the account was activated. Thank you for the documentation about k8s service account.